# How to simplify this function to get the nth number in a sequence

Tags: python, math

So I have a sequence of numbers that will go on forever as 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3... and so fourth. I wanted to make a function that would return  the nth number.

```html
def getGridPos(rowCount):
    county = 0
    for i in range(rowCount):
        if county == 3:
            county = 0  
        county = county + 1
    return county
```

I am not the best at maths and I was wondering if there is a much shorter way or formula to get the same result? perhaps without a loop? I hope I make sense and thanks.

Comment: `def f(n): return n % 4`

Comment: 11 % 4 = 3 but the 11th number in the sequence is 2

Comment: Not if the sequence is 0-indexed. f(0) is 0, f(1) is 1, f(2) is 2, f(3) is 3, f(4) is 0. f(11) is 3. You can write `(n-1) % 4` instead of `n % 4` if you want the sequence to be 1-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by one of the comments, you can do

```
a = list(i % 4 for i in range(4 * 3))

def f(n):
    """
    returns number in sequence a at 1-based index n.
    f(1) -> first element of sequence.
    f(2) -> second element of sequence.
    ...
    f(len(a)) -> last element of sequence.
    """
    return (n - 1) % 4

print(a)
for i in range(1, len(a) + 1):
    print(f(i))
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
```